# Why is the orthogonal complement of a subset of an Hilbert space always equal to the orthogonal complement of the closure of the subset?

Tags: linear-algebra

Everything is in the title I guess. Maybe is the scalar product that defines orthogonality continuous? But why would it be?

Clément

Comment: Yes, it is continuous.  Hint: Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 0):

A scalar product is continuous with respect to the norm it induces in virtue of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.